# Shell Script error: "For loop" is not throwing the expected output

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have json file which extract the color value from the file. For some reason, it only fetch only one block of code & for the rest it throws error.

snippet

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

echo "Add the figma json file path"
read path

figma_json="$(echo -e "${path}" | tr -d '[:space:]')"

echo "*****************************************"


color_values=$(cat $figma_json | jq -r '.color')
color_keys=$(cat $figma_json | jq -r '.color | keys' |sed 's,^ *,,; s, *$,,'| tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '_')

echo $color_keys


for c_key in $color_keys
do

    echo "key string: $c_key"

    echo $color_values | jq ".$c_key.value"
    echo "*********************************************"

done
```

Output

```
trimmed string: "gray1",
{
  "description": "",
  "type": "color",
  "value": "#333333ff",
  "extensions": {
    "org.lukasoppermann.figmaDesignTokens": {
      "styleId": "S:0b49d19e868ec919fac01ec377bb989174094d7e,",
      "exportKey": "color"
    }
  }
}
null
*********************************************
trimmed string: "gray2" //Expected output
"#333333ff"
*********************************************
```

If we look at the second output it prints the hex value of gray2 which is the expected output
Please use the follow link to get the json file
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kBMPvBkE-xmbNVUmvqw7Wrp2Em3K7j-P/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] with enough JSON data in the question itself to reproduce the problem. But the error message is surely telling you that `$c_key.value` contains something which isn't syntactically valid for `jq`. Probably also edit your output to show the value printed just before the error.

Comment: As an aside, http://shellcheck.net/ will point out some common beginner errors, though it can't cringe over how you post-process the output from `jq` when you assign `color_keys`. It is also oddly lenient about the [useless uses of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).

Comment: `$color_keys` is a string containing a json array. `for c_key in $color_keys` can't be used to loop over such a string.

Comment: That said, please add your desired output. This can probably be done in a single JQ call.

Comment: @0stone0 I have added the expected output. Can you please help me here

Comment: Your expected output is unclear, why start with an object and then the hex? Is this the final outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite unclear what you are aiming at, but here's one way how you would read from a JSON file using just one call to `jq`, and most probably without the need to employ `sed` or `tr`. The selection as well as the formatting can easily be adjusted to your liking.

```sh
jq -r '.color | to_entries[] | "\(.key): \(.value.value)"' "$figma_json"
```

```
gray1: #333333ff
gray2: #4f4f4fff
gray3: #828282ff
gray4: #bdbdbdff
gray5: #e0e0e0ff
gray6: #f2f2f2ff
red: #eb5757ff
orange: #f2994aff
yellow: #f2c94cff
green1: #219653ff
green2: #27ae60ff
green3: #6fcf97ff
blue1: #2f80edff
blue2: #2d9cdbff
blue3: #56ccf2ff
purple1: #9b51e0ff
purple2: #bb6bd9ff
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ONLXsDosA5)